# Can we trigger a SP2013 WorkFlow using REST API + Jquery?

Tags: workflow, jquery, designer-workflow, rest

Can anyone suggest whether there  is any possibility how to trigger a SP2013 WorkFlow using REST API & Jquery ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, see for a detail example
[Start workflow using rest call](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Your link provides a way to make a REST call within a workflow which is the opposite of what the user asked for.

Comment: It may not be what original poster was asking, but this exactly what I needed. But I hope there were any updates on this. This article seems to be old. Anyway, thank you @Marc!

Comment: why just a link? No effort... this is not a MS site!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the best way would be to have a workflow that waits for a field to = x then you use the api to update an item and set the field to x.

Answer (score 0):

I have shared how you could start a workflow in sharepoint online on office 365 by calling the REST API at _vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery, basically you will need to do HTTP Post at the end point twice, one to get the workflow subscription and the other to trigger the workflow instance to start, find it here https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2017/01/18/stronger-together-nintex-workflow-cloud-office-365

Answer (score -1):

No, there are no coverage for workflow or taxonomy in SP REST API.

But you can use CSOM:
[Start SharePoint 2013 Workflows with JavaScript Client Object Model](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/08/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html)